# Компиляция QT 5.11 на Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: c++, qt5, raspberry-pi

Raspberry Pi идет в комплекте с QT 5.3 и QT Creator 3.2.1. Есть необходимость обновить версию QT до 5.11. Чтобы была возможность использовать новые возможности QT. Компилирую прямо на Raspberry (про кросскомпиляцию знаю, но в данном случае надо именно на самой малине). Нужно использовать свежую библиотеку QTQuickControls 2.3. Проект совсем маленький, по сути пара датчиков в окошке.
Подскажите, с какими ключами надо собирать из исходников?
Собирал примерно с такими:

```
./configure -release -opensource -confirm-license -nomake tests -nomake examples
```

Конфигурируется нормально, но при сборке сыпятся ошибки.

```
Makefile:128: recipe for target '../../../bin/moc' failed
make[3]: *** [../../../bin/moc] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/qt5/5.10/build/qtbase/src/tools/moc'
Makefile:94: recipe for target 'sub-moc-make_first' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-moc-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/qt5/5.10/build/qtbase/src'
Makefile:48: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/qt5/5.10/build/qtbase'
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'module-qtbase-make_first' failed
make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

UPD

Сконфигурировал со следующими параметрами:

```
../qt-everywhere-src-5.11.2/configure -v -opengl es2 -eglfs -no-gtk -device linux-rasp-pi-g++ \
-device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/ -opensource -confirm-license -reduce-exports \
-force-pkg-config -nomake examples -no-compile-examples -skip qtwayland -skip qtwebkit -skip qtwebengine -release \
-qt-pcre -ssl -evdev -system-freetype -fontconfig -glib -prefix /opt/qt5
```

В конце выдает следующее:

```
Note: Also available for Linux: linux-clang linux-icc
Note: Disabling X11 Accessibility Bridge: D-Bus or AT-SPI is missing.
WARNING: Cross compiling without sysroot. Disabling pkg-config
ERROR: Feature 'pkg-config' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'tests.pkg-config' failed.
ERROR: Feature 'glib' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'libs.glib' failed.
ERROR: Feature 'system-freetype' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'features.freetype && libs.freetype' failed.
ERROR: Feature 'fontconfig' was enabled, but the pre-condition '!config.win32 && features.system-freetype && libs.fontconfig' failed.
```

Что это за ошибки и как их исправить?

делал все по этой инструкции.
https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt_5.4.1_on_a_Raspberry_Pi
Там, правда, про более старую версию, но я делал все по аналогии.

Comment: "пара датчиков в окошке" зачем тогда qt? "при сборке сыпятся ошибки" - какие?

Comment: fat, небось, используете?

Comment: что значит fat? если вы про файловую систему, то, естественно, нет.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте собрать по инструкции https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS
Я по ней собирал Qt 5.9. Думаю может помочь.

Comment: Да, собрал 5.9.8 по ней, 5.12.3 не собирается, что-то с EGL